# Add class to layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

How can I simply add a class to a layer in Photoshop CS5? That class should hold properties like "fill color", "size", etc.

I'm very new to scripting Photoshop so please bear with me =)

Thanks!

Comment: I read the title and I'm thinking, "Gee, I've never worried about my layers not being classy enough. Maybe a snappy hat and a nice tie?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. The classes that are provided by the applications you are working with aren't extensible. But, what you can do to get around this is to create a record making use of Applescript's dynamic typing.

```
set myLayerInformation to {layer:psLayerObj, fill color:fillColorObj, width:mWidth, height:mHeight}
set targetLayer to layer of myLayerInformation
-->RESULT: psLayerObj
```

The records, in turn, could be held in a list that you can maintain along side the layers. It isn't elegant, but it should get the job done.